# Is a Tree constructed by Breadth-First Search a Binary Tree?

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am studying Breadth-First Search. I wanted to ask: is a Tree constructed by Breadth-First Search (i.e., a BFS tree, wherein we store each node's predecessor) a Binary Tree?

Comment: We can say "yes" in general. But there are many types of Binary trees [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). The binary tree constructed by BFS may not always be "strictly binary tree". According to [link](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960215.html) we can say if the tree is constructed using In-order traversal it will be a binary tree.

Comment: `Breadth First Search`ing _what_? A traversal/search in itself doesn't construct anything.

Answer (score 2):

The Tree constructed by Breadth First Search is **not necessarily** a Binary Tree.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Breadth-first_order),*a binary tree is a tree data structure in which each node has **at most two child nodes***.

The node(s) of a tree constructed by `BFS` may contain `any number of Child nodes`.

**Example**:

Following is the **tree** obtained :

[image]

by `Breadth First Search` of following graph:

[image]

Here, the node `Franfurt` in BFS Tree have **3 childs**, hence the definition of **Binary tree** is violated.

Thus, the tree constructed by `BFS` is not necessarily a Binary Tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you explanation and effort!!

Comment: Welcome @DrefD :) If you think the answer was useful, please upvote and accept it. It encourages us to put more efforts.

Comment: a given BFS algorithm might or might not check for the previously visited nodes. That's two different varieties of it.